# I uploaded 2 apps on Google Play and I can install only 1 of them

Tags: android

I have a problem with uploading my apps on Google Play Store. I have 2 apps which rely on each other: game and settings for this game (it was required by teacher). When I uploaded both applications I can install only 1 of them (game or settings) the other one get error from Google Play that cannot be installed. Some information:

- I'm using the same sign key for both.
- Both are in the same project as separated modules.
- When I install these apks manually on emulator there's no problem
- This is not my application, I was asked to add some features
- This app has never been uploaded to Google Play before
- I found in AndroidManifest use of `android:sharedUserId` - could this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd merge the modules and make it two launcher `Activity` (an app can have several launchers)... else you might have issues accessing the one app's preferences from the other app (that's why `android:sharedUserId` is being used); but it's illogical to do so and it's useless complexity. Your teacher ignores the very basics of programming, alike: no complexity beyond necessary. You can probably see by yourself, how you've shot your own feet.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But this project has many files. It would be really annoying to merge all of that, I'm seeing it as a last resort. I'd like to know why this problem occurs.